# Access 2010 SQL - Group By / Order By conflict

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two nearly identical queries operating on essentially the same fields in two different tables. The first query, which works, looks like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(PA_20110126.Account) AS CountOfAccount
SELECT PA_20110126.BuildingSegment, PA_20110126.BuildingGroup
FROM PA_20110126
GROUP BY PA_20110126.BuildingSegment, PA_20110126.BuildingGroup
ORDER BY 
   Switch([PA_20110126].[BuildingSegment]='Residential',0,
    [PA_20110126].[BuildingSegment]='Commercial',1,
    [PA_20110126].[BuildingSegment]='Health',2,
    [PA_20110126].[BuildingSegment]='Religious',3,
    [PA_20110126].[BuildingSegment]='Other',4,
    [PA_20110126].[BuildingSegment]='Government',5),
   PA_20110126.BuildingGroup
PIVOT PA_20110126.[PA Status] In ('CURRENT ', 'DEFAULT ',
  'SATISFIED ', 'NOT SATISFIED ');
```

The second query, below, stops with an error message that says the ORDER BY clause conflicts with the GROUP BY clause.

```
TRANSFORM Count(d20110126.Account) AS CountOfAccount
SELECT d20110126.BCSegment, d20110126.BCGroup
FROM d20110126
GROUP BY d20110126.BCSegment, d20110126.BCGroup
ORDER BY 
   Switch([d20110126].[BCSegment]='Residential',0,
    [d20110126].[BCSegment]='Commercial',1,
    [d20110126].[BCSegment]='Health',2,
    [d20110126].[BCSegment]='Religious',3,
    [d20110126].[BCSegment]='Other',4,
    [d20110126].[BCSegment]='Government',5),
   d20110126.BCGroup
PIVOT d20110126.Borough;
```

What is causing the conflict error in the second query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the queries are basically identical so the problem must be caused by differences  in either the table structure or the table data.  For the fields in question, they appear to be the same data type (since you are comparing them both to the same set of strings), so I'm guessing the problem is with the data itself.

If I had to guess I would say that there is data in the d20110126.BCSegment field that does not equal 'Residential', 'Commercial', 'Health', 'Religious', 'Other', or 'Government'.  If that is the case then the Switch statement will return `Null` for that particular record.

The fix would be to either:

1. sanitize your data (by ensuring through some other means that *all* records had one of the five values you are checking against)
2. add a default 'Else' to your `Switch` statement (eg, `True, 6`) so that the switch statement always returns a value.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I confirmed your first point (using a query and a pivot view), but your second point didn't work -- I still received the same error message. I think my problem may be related to table size, for reasons I don't yet understand. When I reduced the size of the dataset used (from 800,000+ records) with a query that reduced the number of fields _and_ number of records, the query worked. So I can get subsets of the dataset working, but not the entire dataset... Any further thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing immediately comes to mind.  If it is still giving you trouble I'd suggest you ask a new question with the working and non-working SQL statements.